# The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing - Django 2.1 and Python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-class-based-views

I am the form_valid method to save the right question to an answer form. I am using get_object_or_404 to plug the question into the form. However, I keep getting multiple errors, regarding multiple values being returned or not limiting the results to an exact value.

I would like to select the right question, so I can save the answer with the question. Can someone please show me where I am going wrong and how to select the specific question I need? I have been at this for hours - googling and trying different things. This is where I am stuck now:

models.py

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.TextField(default = '')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,
                                    on_delete = models.CASCADE,
                                    related_name = 'answers')
    answerer = models.ForeignKey(Profile,
                                    on_delete = models.CASCADE,
                                    related_name = 'profile_answers')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Answer'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Answers'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

views.py

```
class CreateAnswer(CreateView):
    model = Answer
    fields = ['answer']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        answer = form.save(commit=False)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        institution = Institution.objects.all()
        question = Question.objects.filter(institution=institution)
        answer.question = get_object_or_404(Answer, question=question)
        answer.answerer = profile
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Can you share your model please?

Comment: the problem is you are using Question.objects.filter(institution=institution) which returns queryset but you need a single object so either put  question=question.first() or get one object like Question.objects.get(institution=institution)